# Multiple AJAX forms in the same view in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a view of listings and each listing has a 'favorite' button associated with it. This button submits an AJAX form, either liking or unliking the listing if it has already been liked. Submitting the form calls a like.js.erb method or destroy.js.erb which changes the state of the button.

However, since the js.erb files target the #id of the element I am changing, this only works for the first element. I also can't use a class because that changes all elements.

What's the best way to go about allowing users to like and unlike listings, and changing the view without reloading the page?

I tried giving each of the IDs a unique number based on the listing ID, but can't pass the listing ID to the js.erb files so that doesn't work.

Here is some relevant code:

**/listings/_like.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to like_listing_path(@listing), method: :put, :remote => true, :class => "like-btn" do %>
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
<% end %>
```

**/listings/like.js.erb**

```
$("#like-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('listings/unlike')) %>")
$("#like-size").html('<%= @listing.get_likes.size %>')
```

**/listings/unlike.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to unlike_listing_path(@listing), method: :put, :remote => true,    :class => "unlike-btn" do %>
<i class="fa fa-heart liked"></i>
<% end %>
```

**/listings/unlike.js.erb**

```
$("#like-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('listings/like')) %>")
$("#like-size").html('<%= @listing.get_likes.size %>')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Rails Way**

Just append the ID of the listing to their ID in your erb (since your form is not there I am assuming some structure as the following):

```
<div id="like-form-<%= @listing.id %>">
  <!-- your content -->
</div>
```

and do the same in your JS file:

```js
$("#like-form-<%= @listing.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('listings/unlike')) %>")
$("#like-size-<%= @listing.id %>").html('<%= @listing.get_likes.size %>')
```

This way you will always target the correct element.

**JS way**

Let's say that you have a list of `listings` generated through a loop and each item has the following markup:

```
<div class="listing">
  <!-- your content -->
  <div class="like-form">
    <%= link_to like_listing_path(@listing), class: "like-btn" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to unlike_listing_path(@listing), class: "unlike-btn" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-heart liked"></i>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you could do something write some JS like this:

```js
$(".like-btn, .unlike-btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: el.attr("href"),
    method: post
  }).done(function(data) {
    el.parent().html(data);
  });
});
```

Same thing applies for the number of likes.

**A word on REST**

I have notices that you have two different paths to like and unlike so I am assuming that you have added those paths manually to your `routes.rb`. If you really want to leverage the power of REST you really only need a single path to your listing like and then use `POST` to create a like and `DELETE` to remove a like (i.e. unlike).

Comment: Rails way worked beautifully. Thank you! And you are correct about my routes. Thanks for the tip there.

Comment: @Taylor glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

How about using data attributes?:

```
<%= link_to like_listing_path(@listing), method: :put, :remote => true, :class => "like-btn", :"data-id" => user.id do %>
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
<% end %>
```

Then on your `like` action

```
def like
  @listing = Listing.find params[:"data-id"]
  @listing.like!
end
```